# Application has exceeded serving quota even after making it paid

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

I'm seeing the error:

> This application is temporarily over its serving quota. Please try
>   again later.

Even though I've enabled my app engine app's billing settings. I read on documentation of app-engine quota, they talk about setting daily quota for paid apps but I could not find that configuration.

PS: I did exceed the free quota before I enabled billing. But enabling billing didn't solve it. I do see now that all the quota limits on the compute Admin console are "Okay". But app still doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried clearing out your cache?

Comment: browser cache you mean? yes, I've also tried incognito and another machine.

Comment: I was able to find this: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#How_Resources_are_Replenished

It seems to imply that your Quota will only be replenished tomorrow, regardless of your billing.

Comment: Thanks that might be it! On a similar note, do you know where do I see and modify the Paid apps daily budget limits?

Comment: the budget limit button is in the old console:  https://appengine.google.com/billing/billing_status?&app_id=s~your-app-id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can view and edit the Daily Budget of paid apps in the new Google Developers Console by:

- Go to http://console.developers.google.com
- Login, if not already
- Select your paid app project
- On the left menu bar, go to Compute -> App Engine -> Settings
- You'll see your "Daily Budget" there
- Click "Edit" at the top to change this